# Unresolved Import error (Eclipse, PyDev)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I use Eclipse and PyDev plugin on Windows XP. 
I think the picture I posted below speaks better about my settings. My problem is on this line: `from webmalware.detect.browsers.firefox.defaultfomepage import defaulthomepage`. It says: **'Unresolved Import: defaulthomepage'**. Imports between the defaulthomepage.py and prefjs.py do not cause me a problem. How can I resolve this import problem  ?
[image]
Here are the settings after the answer of Patrick:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see in your image, but it looks like those directories have a file named `__ini__.py` -- this needs to be `__init__.py` -- note the **t**.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I also added one __init__.py file just under src folder. But I still have the same problem on the same line :(

Comment: There needs to be an `__init__.py` in every folder of the import hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I did that, trust me. I re-checked several times

Comment: Is this your own library? Are you modifying an existing package? Is `src` in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Yes, src is on the path too. I am just doing something from scratch.

Comment: Post another picture of your directory structure. You need an `__init__.py` in *every single* directory, including `src`, `webmalware`, `detect`, `browsers`, `firefox` and `defaultfomepage`. (Also -- do you really need the hierarchy to be that deeply-nested? Unless you're writing some massive 10k SLOC project, it seems excessive.) Also post the contents of your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I added the picture after the corrections you asked me, I also removed all empty folders.

Comment: I addeted a `test.py` in the folder `malware` just to try the import deep to defaulthomepage: the problem is there (in subfolders of malware import runs well however)

Comment: What do you mean by "in subfolders of malware import runs well"? Can you post an example of an import that does work? Also -- I'm not sure if this is causing your problem, but I would remove everything below `src` from your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I am so sorry, I meant webmalware folder. Now I resolved the problem but I do not how this logic works. I did `from defaulthomepage import defaulthomepage` from `webmalwareanalysis.py` and it works. Do you understand why ? It does not sound logical to me even if it works.

Comment: You said 'it is excessively deep'. Please, can you explain me why having lot of submodules is a bad programming attitude ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, I can't recreate it by making a similar directory structure. The python best practices, however, [warn against deep nesting](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#avoid-deep-nesting).

Comment: After some tests I understand what caused the problem: I must not add all the subfolders to'PYTHONPATH' unlike all what tutorials ask to do. At least this logic works for me on my computer. I added only /src/